# To What Extent Was Classical Latin Affected by Classical Greek?

Tags: classical-latin, greek

To what extent was Classical Latin influenced by Classical Greek in areas such as pronunciation, grammar, literature, etc.? I would appreciate a quick overview of the list of influences Greek had on Latin and a few examples of those known influences.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a relatively broad question, but a very interesting one. Do you want a quick overview of the influences Greek had on Latin, or do you want to focus on a specific area like grammar? You can ask several separate questions, but it can be good to wait a little between them so you have the chance to learn from previous answers before asking new questions.

Comment: A quick overview of the list of influences and quick overview of those known influences. Let me rephrase the question, and I probably will break it up into different questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer.

The most obvious area of influence is vocabulary. There are a fair number of words that were loaned into Latin from Greek. There are also some terms that were "calqued" from Greek. You can see explanations and examples in this paper: "[An Overview of Latin Morphological Calques on Greek Technical Terms: Formation and Success](https://getd.libs.uga.edu/pdfs/detreville_eleanor_201505_ma.pdf)", by Eleanor Detreville, 2015.

I would say that there was fairly little influence in pronunciation. Loanwords from Greek could use a few sounds that didn't originally occur in Latin, but from what I recall none of the foreign sounds borrowed from Greek into Classical Latin left a lasting mark on the sound inventories of the languages that developed from Latin. (For example, French *rythme,* from Latin *rhythmus,* is pronounced [ʁitm], the same as if it were spelled **ritme.* Greek *th* and *y* aren't associated with unique sounds in French, nor in any other Romance language that I know of.) It is thought that even in the time period of Classical Latin, some speakers may have replaced foreign sounds in Greek words with a similar Latin sound.

Many meters used in Latin poetry, such as [dactylic hexameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactylic_hexameter), were taken from Greek.